# How to know that logs for a block are available

Tags: ethers.js, logs

Following code snippet:

```
    const latestBlock = await provider.getBlockNumber()
    const logs = await provider.getLogs({
      fromBlock: latestBlock,
      toBlock: latestBlock,
    })
    if (logs.length == 0) {
      console.log(`Uh huh, no logs for ${latestBlock}`)
    }
```

often returns no logs and then later, a call for logs on the same block returns logs. Is there a correct way to know when "logs are available" for a given block? Using the `logs.length == 0` seems really sketchy as in theory at least, there could be blocks that contained only txs that did not emit any events.